# gdalwarp cuts off top and right edge of globe from gfs data

Tags: geotiff-tiff, gdalwarp, gdal-calc

I am using data from this GFS forecast: https://nomads.ncdc.noaa.gov/data/gfs4/201905/20190502/gfs_4_20190502_1800_000.grb2

Specifically the bands 102 and 103 containing wind data.

I first combine the u and v components (band 102 and 103) using:

```
gdal_calc.py --overwrite -A gfs_4_20190502_1800_000.grb2 --A_band 102 -B gfs_4_20190502_1800_000.grb2 --B_band 103 --outfile=temp.tiff --calc="sqrt(A*A + B*B)"
```

Then I'm reprojecting the data to an orthographic projection using:

```
gdalwarp -overwrite -t_srs "+proj=ortho +lat_0=14 +lon_0=80 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +R=6371000 +units=m +no_defs" -of GTiff -ts 2000 0 "temp.tiff" "output.tiff"
```

But the end result for that is a globe that's chopped off at the top and right by a few degrees. like here:

[image]

Can't figure out if this is something in the data or something in my commands/projection that's wrong?

Comment: could you add the extents of the images as shown by gdalinfo for the input and outputs